# How can I draw this border?

Tags: android, android-canvas

How can I draw this gradient border(border is fade out to transparent) and radial gradient background?

My code :

```
Drawable/bg.xml
        Radial gradient code is here    
Drawable/border.xml
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>
                    <corners android:topLeftRadius="100dp" android:topRightRadius="100dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="2dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
                    <corners android:topLeftRadius="100dp" android:topRightRadius="100dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:height="5dp"  android:left="30dp" android:right="30dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
                    <corners android:topLeftRadius="100dp" android:topRightRadius="200dp"/>
                    <gradient android:endColor="@color/transparent"
                        android:centerColor="@color/white"
                        android:startColor="@color/transparent"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <gradient android:endColor="@color/white"
                        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:angle="-90" />
                </shape>
            </item>
```

I want this result :

[image: My code result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="100dp" android:topRightRadius="100dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="100dp" android:topRightRadius="100dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item  android:width="40dp" android:left="70dp" android:right="200dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>

            <gradient android:endColor="@color/white"
                android:startColor="@color/transparent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:width="40dp" android:left="240dp" android:right="20dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
            <gradient android:endColor="@color/transparent"
                android:startColor="@color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:left="110dp" android:right="120dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:endColor="@color/white"
                android:startColor="@color/transparent"
                android:angle="-90" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: If background is gradient, is it possible?

Comment: u mean, is it possible to make bg gradient?

Comment: yes, I want use circular gradient background Instead white background for my request design, Is it possible?

Comment: review the code, at the end add another item with shape and gradient - you google a bit for circular gradient

Comment: I added gradient item at the end but only show gradient. I want display border (like your result code) with gradient background instead white background.

Comment: ahhh I see just a sec

Comment: I updated my unswer check out. hope thats what you need. Dont forget to upvote (y) ;)

Comment: thanks a lot for answer. but i mean is full screen gradient background and border over it.

Comment: <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="100dp" android:topRightRadius="100dp"/>
            <gradient android:type="radial" android:gradientRadius="750"
                android:startColor="@color/bpRed" android:endColor="#D4D4D4" />
        </shape>

Comment: then, combine these two in a single third drawable

Comment: having done that, use third created drawable as background to your view

Comment: thanks a lot, that not working for me, can you edit your answer code?

Comment: can you give me tutorial link?

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiv7J3qvO_VAhVhDJoKHcy9CL0QFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vogella.com%2Ftutorials%2FAndroidDrawables%2Farticle.html&usg=AFQjCNECMrNz5ODNWM4O97mphcL1ivhrMQ

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiv7J3qvO_VAhVhDJoKHcy9CL0QFgg5MAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fguide%2Ftopics%2Fgraphics%2F2d-graphics.html&usg=AFQjCNGMLFfNz4sTa1WHG1O2uJ4J_fXJBQ

Comment: thanks a lot. I writed that code as combine 2 drawable, but that not working. I edited my question then added my code and added result image that i want.

Answer (score 1):

Create this rectangle.xml file inside the drawable folder.
Copy this code into it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:endColor="#000000"
                android:startColor="#FFFFFF" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="5dp"
                android:left="5dp"
                android:right="5dp"
                android:top="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#af25e1" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <size
                android:width="250dp"
                android:height="150dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and set it as the background to your container.
You can change it according to your needs

Hope it works for you.